# Mientras visualizo mi sitio web en el localhost de xampp todo bien, la codificación UTF-8 funciona, el problema está en cuanto lo subo a un servidor

Tags: php, linux, servidor, utf-8, centos

Cuando subo mi sitio web a un servidor Linux Centos 7 no toma en cuenta la codificación UTF-8 de los HTML, también la tengo que asignar en los archivos php? También leía que talvez no está habilitada la extensión de MySQL en php.ini alguien me puede decir qué puede ser? O qué tengo que comprobar?

Comment: Es un VPS? revisar el *php.ini* (tiene que tener por defecto `default_charset = "utf-8";`), el archivo de configuración del web server (nginx, apache, etc). A veces en el archivo de configuración de mysql tambien hay que revisar (`default-character-set=UTF-8`)

Comment: QUé error o comportamiento estás viendo diferente? No nos has contado eso y dependiendo de lo que veas, el ajuste es diferente. Ve a [edit] y cuéntanos cuál es el error

Answer (score 0):

No se si te servirá, yo para no tener problemas con la codificación, en la conexión utilizo este método:

```
mysqli_set_charset($conex, 'UTF8');
```

Donde $conex es la conexión a la BD.